# Conexion de 2 redes de internet a un solo concentrador

Tags: redes

que tal buenas tardes,

quisiera saber si hay manera de en un solo concentrador(switch) colocar 2 conexiones a Internet por si una llega a fallar, la otra siga manteniendo estable las conexiones.

Pero quisiera saber si me pueden a apoyar en también implementar una mejor opción.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: mmmmm creo que con un sqotch comun y corriente no se puede, deve de ser un fortinet o similar, espero que te sirva de ayuda mi respuesta.

Comment: Te invito a hacer la pregunta en la comunidad de 

[Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). Si necesitas ayuda con el inglés te recomendaría el traductor [Traductor](https://www.deepl.com/translator)